# The five problems of the six domino tiles

Tags: geometry, dominoes

Here is a set a problems (regarding domino tiles) of a famous Portuguese newspaper weekly magazine.
For each problem you have $6$ domino tiles and the goal is always to place them touching each other by the rules of each problem. The touching between two tiles corners is not valid:
[image]

You have to display all the six tiles on each problem.

**Problem 1:**

> Display the six tiles so that each one touches only two of the others.

**Problem 2:**

> Display the six tiles so that each one touches only three of the others.

**Problem 3:**

> Display the six tiles so that each one touches only four of the others.

**Problem 4:**

> Display the six tiles so that each one touches all of the others.

**Problem 5:**

> Display the six tiles so that
>
> - one touches only one of the other
> - one touches only two of the others
> - one touches only three of the others
> - one touches only four of the others
> - one touches all of the others

**Note #1:** I decided to put all the problems on the same post mainly because all of them have the same statement, but also because some of them are really easy.

**Note #2:** You don't really have to use domino tiles. You could picture $2\times1$ blocks instead (the values of the domino faces don't matter here). I just used domino tiles to be faithful to the original post.

Comment: In problem 5 you only specify what five of the dominoes do. Is that correct?

Comment: @JaapScherphuis, yes!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Problem 1:

> [image]
>  (there's a hole in the center, it's not a tile)

Problem 2:

> [image] on top of [image]

Problem 3:

> [image] on top of [image]

Problem 4:

> [image]
>  Not exactly to scale, Excel isn't the right tool for these kind of drawings. The blue ones are $6\sqrt2 \times 3\sqrt2$ cells wide, but the configuration works if they're $8 \times 4$ cells wide as the black ones.

Problem 5:

> [image]
>  (same caveat as Problem 4)
>  The top right tile touches only one other tile
>  The bottom right tile touches two others
>  The bottom left tile touches three others (as does the horizontal one)
>  The bottom center tile touches four others
>  The blue tile (on top of the others) touches all others

Comment: I’ve never thought of 3D!

Comment: Just the fourth and the fifth to go :)

Comment: @Pspl I think I've solved them as well. Thanks for sharing the puzzle!

Comment: @Glorfindel, yes! You did solve them all. The only different solution I have from you is regarding the last problem. But yours works as well :)

Answer (score 4):

Problem 1

> [image]
> The middle is a hole

Comment: Can you figure out different solutions for the others? Relatively to @Glorfindel answer... I know different solutions for all of them, except for the fourth.

Comment: @Pspl Which problems do not have 2D solutions?

Comment: Only the first one has a 2D solution (as far as I know).