# Minimal 2D pattern for domino tiles where each tile touches three others

Tags: geometry, dominoes

Inspired by [The five problems of the six domino tiles](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/100588/11110), where one of the tasks was to place six domino tiles so that each tile touches three others (corner / edge touches don't count). My solution there required putting domino tiles on top of each other, and the OP (not the author of the puzzle) [thought there is no 2D solution](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/100588/the-five-problems-of-the-six-domino-tiles#comment286023_100590).

Now, if we increase the number of tiles, we can certainly make a 2D solution, e.g. the following one using 16 tiles:

[image]

A natural question/puzzle is therefore to ask:

**What pattern uses the minimum number of tiles?**

Rules:

- The tiles are twice as long as wide
- Tiles have to be laid out in a two-dimensional pattern
- Each tile needs to touch exactly three others; only touches between edges count
- Just to be pedantic: there needs to be at least one tile

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on your 16-tile example I reduced it down to

> 8 dominoes.
>  [image]

Sketch of proof why this is minimal:

> The number of dominoes must be even because of the [handshaking lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handshaking_lemma). So it only remains to show that 6 is impossible.
>  Thinking about it as a graph with the dominoes as vertices with edges connecting touching dominoes, then we are looking for a planar, 3-regular, simple graph with 6 vertices. The only such graph is that formed by the edges of a triangular prism. It has three 4-sided faces and two triangular faces.
>  Unfortunately we need one face to have at least 5 edges, since one face forms the outside boundary of the graph, and it is impossible to have four dominoes fully enclosing the other two. So it is not possible with 6 dominoes.
>
>  I did not prove the assertion that there is only one planar, 3-regular, simple graph with 6 vertices, and I don't really know how. Still, it is easy to convince yourself that if you start with a hexagon and turn it into a 3-regular graph by adding diagonals, then the added diagonals must cross. The same happens to a pentagon with a sixth vertex somewhere inside.

Comment: I think you have found the minimum solution...

Comment: @Glorfindel I've added a sketchy proof.